# Delay in wrapping up 2022 election

Tags: discussion

We're experiencing some issues with wrapping up [your first election](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/election/1), and are currently trying to assess what the root cause is. As far as we can tell, this is a problem on the OpaVote site, not with Stack Exchange.

As soon as we know, you'll know. The election results will be posted once we can get them.

Thank you for your patience, and stay tuned for further updates.